# I want to set control (chart) fit in screen when I rotate content page in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working with xamarin forms.
Also using Syncfusion Chart
I wanted to set controls inside ContentPage which are like this

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:name="Stack1">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:name="Stack2">
        <label x:name="lbl1"></label>
        <image x:name="img1"></image>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout x:name="Stack3">
        <syncfusion:chart x:name=chart1> 
       </syncfusion:chart>
    </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
```

[image: Something like this]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need StackLayout, you need [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) control:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefenitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefenitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition/>
     <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <label Grid.Column="0" x:name="lbl1"></label>
        <image Grid.Column="1" x:name="img1"></image>
        <syncfusion:chart Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:name=chart1> 
       </syncfusion:chart>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Access Denied, but this didn't work,

Comment: What happens is, all controls go to left side and chart goes out from the side of the bottom of the chart

Comment: it works in IOS but not in Android, chart goes upside (which is right side of screen) out of screen.

Comment: Problem solved with Grid Control, Thanks Access Denied.

Comment: Glad to hear that. @harsh92 There is upvote button for thank you on this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the orientation of the page like this:

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SizeChanged += PageSizeChanged;
}

void PageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isPortrait = this.Height >= this.Width;
    if(!isPortrait)
    {
         //move label and image and make the chart bigger here
    }
}
```